# Running a node server at certain times of day in an Ubuntu environment?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart

I'm running my small node app on an Ubuntu server, I can use a simple Upstart script to automatically start the node server on server launch.

However, I'd like the node app to run at particular times of day -- what are my options for implementing this? 
Is it best to do this within the Node app or from the Ubuntu environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `cron`?

```
$ crontab -e

# in the editor that opens:
0 */2 * * * ~/path/to/your/node/script.js > /tmp/out.log 2> /tmp/err.log
```

That will run your `script.js` every 2 hours, ie 0:00 (midnight), 2:00, 4:00, etc. It also logs to your /tmp directory, but that's entirely optional.

Comment: I'm test this out, however I can't get crontab to execute a nodejs script: * * * * * /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/test.js Is this right?

Comment: What does `/var/log/cron.log` say?

Comment: I don't have that file, I have /var/log/syslog which shows :

"Mar 18 18:21:01 ip-172-31-27-83 CRON[11703]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/checkip.js)" 

This is the same as the crontab. 

i've read that I might need to include #!/bin/sh at the top of the node script?

Comment: No, you would not put `#!/bin/sh` at the top of a node script, you would put `#!/usr/bin/nodejs` and then `chmod +x /home/ubuntu/checkip.js`. But that's optional...your cron job is definitely being run. Add the logging bit (`> /tmp/out.log 2> /tmp/err.log`) to the end of the line. The default behavior is to email any output to the user running the job, in your case `ubuntu`. Is email setup for that user?

Comment: No email has been set up for that user! I'm looking through the syslog and I've noticed this error after each cron " postfix/sendmail[11105]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory"..maybe something to so with that? 
I've looked at the tmp/out.log and tmp/err.log and both remain empty after I run the cron?